# How to get a reference to the main window launched by MainWindow.xib

Tags: swift

I am new to `swift` and `xcode`. I want to add ui elements programmatically to an existing application that already has a `MainWindow.xib` .  I would also like to put breakpoints and logging in the main window. Where is the programmatic interface to the main window?

Here are what seem to be the most relevant files of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the information I was looking for on this question.

[Stop Using Storyboard, Start Building UI 100% Programmatically [Updated]](https://medium.com/@rajatamil/stop-using-storyboard-start-building-ui-100-%20programmatically-c19c34c4f5f5)

This article goes into how to divest the application of the dependencies on the `MainWindow` .  There are too many details to go into all of them here but a summary of the points discussed:

- Issues with using `Storyboard`:

  1. IBAction/IBOutlet Issues: When I refactored the code by changing the IBOutlet/IBAction variable name after a few days of work, the app crashed for no apparent reason and I had to reconnect it every time that happened.
  2. Nested Views: When I added a few nested subviews under a view, it was hard to adjust when I wanted two subviews to be placed one behind another. On top of that, adding constraints to them was one of the most frustrating things to do.
  3. Compile Time
- Steps to remove Storyboard

  - STEP #1: Get Rid of Storyboard & it’s references
  - STEP #2 Set A Root View Controller

  Code needed:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

- STEP #3 Add Subviews Programmatically
- Step #4: Add Auto Layout Constraints Programmatically

I also read the comments which included agreements and disagreements. One mentioned that `SwiftUI` might be another approach.  However it has its own limitations.